# Can somebody help me with some pros and cons of the Cocktail sort?

Tags: sorting

Cocktail Sort is a variation of Bubble sort. The Bubble sort algorithm always traverses elements from left and moves the largest element to its correct position in first iteration and second largest in second iteration and so on. Cocktail Sort traverses through a given array in both directions alternatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site!  I hadn't heard of Cocktail Sort before but I found this resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cocktail-sort/.

Pro:
The algorithm has the same complexity class of Bubble Sort: `O(n^2)`, but it tends to be faster by a factor of 2.

Con:
Bubble Sort has the simplest code implementation of all sorting algorithms, but Cocktail sort is a little more complex.  Insertion Sort or Selection Sort are both relatively simple and perform `O(n * log(n)),` might be preferable.